# Why navigator.geolocation.getcurrentposition is not available with react native and expo

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, geolocation, expo

I am trying to get some position information from a device, I am using React-native, Expo, and ExpoGo on android mobile, I am not using simulators, the application is working with ExpoGo on Android, but geolocation is not working, it sends this error message every time:
`window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition is not available. Import and execute installWebGeolocationPolyfill() from expo-location to add it, or use the expo-location APIs instead.`

Please help me find the solution to this issue.

This is the App code used:

```
import { Text, View} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";

const API_KEY = "";
const URL = `https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=${API_KEY}&latlng=`;

export default function WhereAmI() {
  const [address, setAddress] = useState("loading...");
  const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState();
  const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    function setPosition({ coords: { latitude, longitude } }) {
      setLongitude(longitude);
      setLatitude(latitude);
      fetch(`${URL}${latitude},${longitude}`)
        .then(
          (resp) => resp.json(),
          (e) => console.error(e)
        )
        .then(({ results }) => {
          setAddress(results[0].formatted_address);
        });
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);

    let watcher = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      setPosition,
      (err) => console.error(err),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true }
    );

    return () => {
      navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watcher);
    };
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Address: {address}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Latitude: {latitude}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.label}>Longitude: {longitude}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I fixed this problem, and this worked for me.

1. geolocation on iOS and Android:

- I installed the expo-location package by running `expo install expo-location`.
- I imported expo location in App.js as Location: `import * as Location from 'expo-location'`.
- I used the #installWebGeolocationPolyfill function that polyfills #navigator.geolocation for interop with the core React Native
  and Web API approach to geolocation just before using of the #navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition like
  this:

```
       # ... some code

      Location.installWebGeolocationPolyfill()
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);

      # ... some code
```

2.The error 'formatted_address' is undefined:
That because there is no API_KEY, you should get an API key from Google, instead, I just Added it manually into the #setPosition function like this:

```
 #...some code

.then(
          ({ results }) => {
            results[0]={formatted_address:"here"}
            setAddress(results[0].formatted_address)
          },

 #...some code
```